# how do you write the output of this script to a file

Tags: python-2.7

gives you the no.of days in a particular month

```
enter code here
month_name = input("Input the name of Month: ")
if month_name == "February":
   print("No. of days: 28/29 ")
elif month_name in ("April", "June", "September", "November"):
   print("No. of days: 30 ")
elif month_name in ("January", "March", "May", "July", "August", "October", "December"):
   print("No. of days: 31 ")
else:
   print("Wrong month name/write the name of the month with an uppercase at the begining")
```

Comment: I'm using Python-2.7. Thanks for answering my question but I still have a problem,how would you modify your script so that the "no.of days= whatever no." shows up on the console. And the name of the month shows up in the my.file.txt. ?

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question Python-2.7 but it looks to me as if you are actually writing Python 3.

Which means there is an issue with your code: when you use `input()` in Python 2 it expects the input to be a valid Python expression. But you are not telling your user to enclose their input in quotes. If they respond to your prompt like this (as any reasonable user would):

```
Input the name of Month: January
```

your program will fail with the error `NameError: name 'January' is not defined`. In Python 2.7 use `raw_input()` instead.

Also in Python 2.7, you need to have `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your program to get the same behaviour as Python 3. I'm not going to offer you the Python 2 `print` statement syntax because there is no point in your learning it.

To write to a file, first `open` it and then name it as the `file` parameter of your `print()` call, like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open("myfile.txt","w") as output:
    month_name = raw_input("Input the name of Month: ") # change to input() in Python 3
    if month_name == "February":
       print("No. of days: 28/29 ",file=output)
    elif month_name in ("April", "June", "September", "November"):
       print("No. of days: 30 ",file=output)
    elif month_name in ("January", "March", "May", "July", "August", "October", "December"):
       print("No. of days: 31 ",file=output)
    else:
       print("Wrong month name/write the name of the month with an uppercase at the beginning")
```

Apart from `raw_input()` this code will work in Python 2.7 and in Python 3.6.